# Python - easiest way to Join Strings In List by count of characters with no importing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python3, no imports allowed

I have a list that I want to combine the number the next letter (ex: ('0','A') and ignore the empty string in the beginning but have an empty string paired with the 4 (ex: ('4', '')

```
string = ['', '0', 'A', '0', 'B', '1', 'B', '2', 'A', '4']
```

Then the output looks like this:

```
[(0, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'), (4, '')]
```

Comment: hope to find someone doing your homework?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `string` has a valid form, it will be

```
>>> string = ['0', 'A', '0', 'B', '1', 'B', '2', 'A', '4', '']
>>> list(zip(string[::2], string[1::2]))
[('0', 'A'), ('0', 'B'), ('1', 'B'), ('2', 'A'), ('4', '')]
```

I think you can handle those `''` at the beginning and the end by yourself, and get the `string` to the right form.

Answer (score 0):

```
zip([int(i) for i in string[1::2]],string[2::2]).append((4, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
string.append(string[0])
new = []
for i in range(1, len(string) - 1, 2):
    new.append((int(string[i]), string[i + 1]))
>>> new

[(0, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (1, 'B'), (2, A), (4, '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in fewer lines, however I think this is a little easier to understand.

```
string = ['', '0', 'A', '0', 'B', '1', 'B', '2', 'A', '4']


def joinalnum(my_string):

    def push_back_non_alnums(my_string):
    # Sends all non alphanumeric values to the back of the list
        non_alnums = []
        for index, element in enumerate(my_string):
            if not element.isalnum():
                non_alnums.append(my_string.pop(index))
        return my_string + non_alnums

    def couple(my_string):
        return list(zip(my_string[::2], my_string[1::2]))

    my_string = push_back_non_alnums(my_string)
    my_string = couple(my_string)

    return my_string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(joinalnum(string))
```